# Exclude one URL from script

Tags: javascript

I use this code to **prevent** the visitors of my website to **copy-paste** its content.

```
<script>document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());</script>
<script>element.on(?:copy|cut|paste)</script>
```

I was wondering if it were possible to **exclude one URL from this script**?
It would help since it's for the tracking and customers would use copy-paste

Let me know, thanks you in advance :)

Comment: A better idea might be to just not include the script on the page you want to exclude it from.

Comment: You can get the current url by checking `window.location`.

Comment: The second one won't work anyway. And why not just not include the script when you don't want it? What prevents you from doing that?

Comment: Also understand that people can easily get around a mechanism like that.

Comment: Generally there is no any javascript will prevent user from copying contents, simply, they may disable it or select and `CTRL+C`.
However, you may call this functionality from a function in which a check for `document.location` occurred before listen to the event.

Comment: Additionally, if you want more restricted environment, you may code your own web browser and obligatory make your website accessible using your web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());
```

you could do something like

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => {
    if (window.location.href !== 'http://example.com/exclude/') {
        event.preventDefault()
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you, I even found a better way: exclude the paste event !